# CSS3 - transform:translateY( out of screen )

Tags: jquery, css, web

I am trying to add a slide up from down.

And adding starting position:

```
    transform:translateY(200%)
```

which works fine if the scroll area is not too big.

```
    transform:translate(-200%)
```

works better because it moves relative to the top and that part can't grow.

**Is there a good way around this?**

Using

```
   transform: translateY(50000px);
```

and will potentially **affect animations** as they have to move over larger 
areas.

What is a good approach to this problem?

**---------- Edit -----------**

Actually, it appears as if the scrolling area is getting larger with larger translateY meaning that it never actually gets out of the viewport, which might be the problem here. I am not sure how to resolve this though.

Comment: Don't use transform....it sounds like you need to use absolute positioning but without knowing the specific circumstances it's hard to offer an advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears as if

```
     translate3D(-100%, 100%, 0);
```

resolves the issue.